# Ubuntu 17.10 taking long time to boot

Tags: boot

My system specs are Lenovo Thinkpad

- i5-2.3GHz
- 8 Gb Ram

Some details are :

```
$ systemd-analyze
```

Startup finished in 26.156s (kernel) + 30.274s (userspace) = 56.431s

and

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
      9.700s snapd.service
      8.771s dev-sda2.device
      7.346s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.180s ModemManager.service
      4.109s NetworkManager.service
      3.910s accounts-daemon.service
      3.349s keyboard-setup.service
      3.162s dev-loop1.device
      3.009s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      2.983s dev-loop3.device
      2.787s speech-dispatcher.service
      2.567s fwupd.service
      2.349s systemd-logind.service
      2.347s postfix@-.service
      2.342s networking.service
      2.277s gpu-manager.service
      2.271s udisks2.service
      2.232s pppd-dns.service
      2.230s vboxweb-service.service
      2.227s rsyslog.service
      2.099s dev-loop0.device
      1.782s bluetooth.service
      1.728s dev-loop2.device
      1.606s alsa-restore.service
      1.602s lm-sensors.service
      1.601s switcheroo-control.service
      1.484s polkit.service
      1.416s apparmor.service
      1.328s grub-common.service
      1.234s packagekit.service
      1.145s avahi-daemon.service
      1.082s apport.service
       852ms systemd-udevd.service
       810ms tlp.service
       591ms snap-core-3440.mount
       533ms thermald.service
       502ms lightdm.service
       479ms systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service
       477ms snap-atom-106.mount
       447ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       445ms colord.service
       441ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
       422ms upower.service
       396ms kerneloops.service
       391ms vboxautostart-service.service
       342ms snap-core-3604.mount
       286ms wpa_supplicant.service
       275ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       267ms systemd-resolved.service
       243ms console-setup.service
       231ms setvtrgb.service
       229ms dns-clean.service
       227ms snap-atom-76.mount
```

and

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain

    graphical.target @29.463s
└─multi-user.target @29.463s
  └─postfix.service @29.461s +1ms
    └─postfix@-.service @27.112s +2.347s
      └─network-online.target @27.107s
        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @19.759s +7.346s
          └─NetworkManager.service @15.649s +4.109s
            └─dbus.service @14.501s
              └─basic.target @13.808s
                └─sockets.target @13.807s
                  └─snapd.socket @13.797s +7ms
                    └─sysinit.target @13.748s
                      └─systemd-timesyncd.service @12.505s +275ms
                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @12.310s +193ms
                          └─local-fs.target @12.275s
                            └─boot-efi.mount @12.237s +37ms
                              └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0190\x2dF0CF.service @12.070s +134ms
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0190\x2dF0CF.device @12.068s
```

I have tried my best to google for the solutions but couldn't find any. 
Any links to existing solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Look through the services to see if there are some that don't need to be part of the startup. You seem to be starting Postfix, vboxweb, your modem (which slows the whole networking stack), and much more. You have a lot installed! Honestly, I think 56 sec from poweron pretty decent for all that.

Comment: If you don't already use a SSD, get one. This speeds things up considerably.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/987368/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything about it as it is the typical time it takes to load Ubuntu systems. You can try disabling some services but it might be risky and cause system instability.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the what is causing the hold up you can do the following to enable boot messages.

1. Run:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and remove the parameters `quiet` and `splash`.
3. Save the file and close the editor.
4. Finally, start a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   to update GRUB's configuration file.

Comment: Yeah, But I already done that.

Comment: @RitikKumar If you did that already, can you add that to your question as otherwise more people will propose to do this if user760933 deletes his answer.